# Cypress: req.followRedirect = false is not preventing the redirection from happening

Tags: angular, cypress

Here's my test. I took it from the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Options). Since I am testing that when a particular button is clicked, it should redirect to a different domain, this is how I wrote the test.

```
it('should redirect to some external website on click', () => {
  cy.intercept(
    'GET',
    'http://localhost.com:4100?*',
    (req: CyHttpMessages.IncomingHttpRequest) => {
      req.followRedirect = false;
    }
  ).as('redirect');

  cy.get('#some-button').click(); //Clicking this button does the redirection
  cy.wait('@redirect')
      .its('request.url')
      .should('include', 'value-A')
      .and('include', 'value-B');

});
```

All the assertions are passing. However, it keeps redirecting me to the external url.

according tot the documentation, this is how to prevent the browser to follow the redirect.

```
cy.request({
  url: '/dashboard',
  followRedirect: false, // turn off following redirects
}).then((resp) => {
  // redirect status code is 302
  expect(resp.status).to.eq(302)
  expect(resp.redirectedToUrl).to.eq('http://localhost:8082/unauthorized')
});
```

How to prevent the browser from redirecting to the external website? `followRedirect = false` is not working.

Comment: I have a similar problem, except that most of the time it DOES seem to prevent them, except for once in a while it does NOT.  Using cypress 9.3.0